# How to prevent multiple DB lookups in Laravel and share state within a single request?

Tags: php, laravel, service

Sorry, I don't really know the proper way to word this, but I want to avoid doing the same DB query several times and running a few functions within the same request.

In Javascript frameworks, in the past I would use a service, where I could save some state and inject it into a few different places so I didn't have to do the work multiple times, save some state.

Is there something like this in Laravel? I've read about service containers and providers, but the documentation was confusing for me and I'm not sure if that will do the job?

Basically, I want to do a DB lookup, run a few functions, and then save some state, where I can pick it up elsewhere in the app.

Comment: You can do this with the container. but there's probably a better way.  Maybe give an example so this isn't so broad.

Comment: You want to try cache? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/cache

Comment: @Devon Eg. Website Service: -Parses URL from request, -Search/Loads website model, -Checks Auth State, -Compares Website model against user model, and sets state for a few permissions. Runs once and then can have the data recalled in different parts of the app without having to reinstantiate a class and do the whole lookup each time.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Isn't there some way I can have a class and state shared between other classes during the request lifecycle? Cache would be good if I was trying to save across multiple requests and a bit overkill and slow for a single request.